# how to link the openssl library with the arm-cross compiler

Tags: c, gcc, openssl, pyopenssl, armcc

I have application test.c which by using gcc on host(on ubuntu) machine i have succeed in compilation and successfully ran the application program on host.

now I would like to cross compile the same application with arm-cross compiler for `LPC1788`. please guide me how to link the openssl library files

My Mkakefile with GCC

```
CC  = gcc  

 CFLAGS = -D__XMLSEC_FUNCTION__=__FUNCTION__ -DXMLSEC_NO_XKMS=1
-DXMLSEC_NO_CRYPTO_DYNAMIC_LOADING=1 -I/usr/include/xmlsec1
-I/usr/include/libxml2 -DXMLSEC_OPENSSL_097=1
-DXMLSEC_CRYPTO_OPENSSL=1 -DXMLSEC_CRYPTO=\"openssl\ -DUNIX_SOCKETS -D XML_SECURITY

 LDFLAGS = -lcrypto -I/usr/include/libxml2 -lxml2 -I/usr/include/xmlsec1 -lxmlsec1    

all:
   $(CC) src/test.c -o test $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS)
```

by changing the compiler I used the following Makefile

```
CC = /home/amarayya/doc/tools/arm-2010q1/bin/arm-uclinuxeabi-gcc
CFLAGS = -D__XMLSEC_FUNCTION__=__FUNCTION__ -DXMLSEC_NO_XKMS=1
-DXMLSEC_NO_CRYPTO_DYNAMIC_LOADING=1 -I/usr/include/xmlsec1
-I/usr/include/libxml2 -DXMLSEC_OPENSSL_097=1
-DXMLSEC_CRYPTO_OPENSSL=1 -DXMLSEC_CRYPTO=\"openssl\ -DUNIX_SOCKETS -D XML_SECURITY

LDFLAGS = -lcrypto -L/usr/include/libxml2 -lxml2 -L/usr/include/xmlsec1 -lxmlsec1

all:
$(CC) src/test.c -o test $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS)
```

which leading to these errors

```
fatal error: openssl/rsa.h: No such file or directory
fatal error: openssl/rsa.h: No such file or directory
```

what causing these errors and how to over come

Comment: have you cross compiled openssl for arm?

Comment: Also try by adding  `CFLAGS = -isystem /usr/include/openssl`.

Comment: it resulting the same result No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use your host libraries when compiling for a different architecture. First, you need to cross compile all non-standard libraries (libxml, libopenssl) for your target machine (i.e. ARM).

Basically, you need to download the source code for these libraries and configure it with

```
--host=arm-uclinuxeabi --prefix=SOME_HOST_DIR
```

(or something similar - you might check the README files)
assuming, that you have your cross compiler in PATH.

These libraries might also require more libraries to be cross compiled.

When compiling your application you should use these cross compiled libraries.

Comment: I have cross compiled openssl  and copied the these libcrypto.a and libssl.a in the cross compiler path then also resulting in the same errors.

Comment: Do you have the required header file (rsa.h)? Check the installation directory of the cross-compiled opencssl. You would need to point your compiler to this directory - something like -I SOME_HOST_DIR/usr/include

Comment: i can find these .h files in path /usr/include/openssl/

Comment: buy using this link I have compiled openssl http://embeddedcoaching.blogspot.in/2013/10/openssl-cross-compilation-for-arm-on.html

Comment: /usr/include contains host headers, you need to use the cross compiled version. Check the openssl build/installation directory. The link, you provided is a bit confusing - you should not need to use sudo for cross compiling (you don't want to overwrite host libraries with cross compiled versions).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11796127/how-to-cross-compile-c-library-with-dependencies  This post might help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57087/discussion-between-amar-and-kayrick).

Comment: `--host=arm-uclinuxeabi` - OpenSSL is *not* an autotools project.

Comment: AS i am trying its giving some errors these are due to wrong paths for library,it will be helpful if given details to compile openssl for particular controllers(any arm controller)

Comment: @jww As from the above valuable suggestions i didn’t got the result. it necessary to compile openssl library using cross compiler and with architecture dependencies.? if so any links or docs will be helpful..? 
how to give path route for it...? is we need to install the cross compiled openssl on host..? how can we give link for the same...?